# Characteristic polynomial of left multiplication equals minimal polynomial of element

Tags: linear-algebra, field-theory, linear-transformations, galois-theory, minimal-polynomials

I'm trying to answer the following question:

> Let $E/F$ be an extension field of prime degree $l$ and let $α ∈ E \setminus F$. Let $M_α$ be $F$-linear
>   map induced by the multiplication by $α$:
>
> $M_α : E \rightarrow E \\ \space\space\space\space u \mapsto α · u$.
>
> Show that the characteristic polynomial of $M_α$ is equal to the minimal polynomial of $α$.

I'm given a hint to use Cayley-Hamilton, and I can see that since $\chi(x) = \det (x I - M_α)$ we get $\chi(α) = 0$ as $(α I - M_α)(x) = αx - αx = 0 $ $\forall x$, and so applying Cayley-Hamilton we see that the minimal polynomial of $α$ divides the characteristic polynomial of $M_α$.

I can't, however, see how to go about showing the converse - I don't know how to show the characteristic polynomial divides the minimal and hence that they're equal.

If anyone can spot what I'm missing or offer another solution I'd really appreciate it!

Comment: The hypothesis you haven’t used is that the extension is of prime degree. What is the possible degree of the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$, given that $F\subseteq F(\alpha)\subseteq E$?